# Relation between the smoothness of a function and the decay of its Fourier coefficients

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, smooth-functions

Let $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb C$ be a smooth (with that I mean $C^\infty$) $1$-periodic function. So there are $a_n \in \mathbb C$ with
$$f(x) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb Z} a_n \exp(2 \pi i nx).$$
**Question 1**: What can we say about the decay of the $a_n$?

On the other hand: Let's have $b_n \in \mathbb C$ such that
$$g(x) := \sum_{n \in \mathbb Z} b_n \exp(2 \pi i nx)$$
converges absolutely for all $x$, which is equivalent to
$$\sum_{n \in \mathbb Z} |b_n| < \infty.$$
**Question 2**: Can we infer that for very fast decay of the $b_n$ (if yes, how fast?) the function $g$ is smooth?

The best result would be an equivalence. So that there is one magical bound sich that the function is smooth if and only if the Fourier coefficients decay faster than this magical bound.

Comment: integrating by parts it is easy to show that $a_n=o_k(1/|n|^k), n \ge 1$ for any $k \ge 0$ and conversely if that happens $f$ is smooth ($C^{\infty}$ - for smoothness only to order $k$ the problem is much more complicated) if $a_n=O(e^{-a|n|}$ for some $a>0$ then $f$ is (real) analytic and can be extended to a complex analytic function on an annulus around the unit circle and vice-versa;

Comment: for smoothness to order $k$ one has necessary conditions (eg $f$ differentiable $k$ times and $f^{(k)}$ integrable then $a_n=o(1/|n|^k)$ which is precisely Riemann-Lebesgue lemma for $k=0$), but not really sharp sufficient conditions as of course that would entail sharp conditions for $a_n \to 0, |n| \to \infty$ to be Fourier coefficients and that is a notoriously hard problem; I would say that the only simple conditions are square integrability (weakest simple such) or absolute convergence for $a_nn^k$